# Font Resizer Javascript Not Working In IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, fonts, resize, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to put a font-resizer on my company' website since a lot of our customers are the elderly and they have no idea about Ctrl + "+".

Here are the codes we have. The resizer works fine under FF, Chrome, and IE9. But not in IE8 and IE7. I omit the create cookies/read cookies parts here.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {.....codes for create cookies......}

function changeFont(incfont) {
    try{
        var p = document.getElementsByClassName('resizable');
        for(n=0; n<p.length; n++) {
            if(p[n].style.fontSize) {
                var size = parseInt(p[n].style.fontSize.replace("px", ""));
            } else {
                var size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p[n],null).getPropertyValue('font-size').replace("px", ""));
            }
            p[n].style.fontSize = size+ incfont + 'px';
        }

        p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        for(n=0; n<p.length; n++) {
            if(p[n].style.fontSize) {
                var size = parseInt(p[n].style.fontSize.replace("px", ""));
            } else {
                var size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p[n],null).getPropertyValue('font-size').replace("px", ""));
            }
            p[n].style.fontSize = size+ incfont + 'px';
        }
    } catch(err) {}
}

function readCookie(name) { ....code for read cookies ....}

function increaseFontSize() {
    var inc=0;
    try {
        var x = readCookie('textsize')
        if (x && x!=0) {
            x = parseInt(x);
            inc = x;
        }
    } catch (e) {}

    if (inc<3) {
        inc++;
        changeFont(1);
        createCookie('textsize',inc,1);
    }
}

function decreaseFontSize() {
    var inc=0;
    try {
        var x = readCookie('textsize')
        if (x && x!=0) {
            x = parseInt(x);
            inc = x;
        }
    } catch (e) {}

    if (inc>0) {
        inc--;
        changeFont(-1);
        createCookie('textsize',inc,1);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
YN

Comment: from a duplicate: http://jsfiddle.net/zgqN7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems overcomplex to me, I will suggest you a different approach, set a base text size for the page body, and then for the rest elements set font-sizes in percentage, that way when you want to resize the text of all the site you just have to do:

```
$("body").css("font-size", newFontSize);
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson very much for your answer! Your idea makes sense. As a javascript newbie, this following question might look stupid to you. Can I replace $('body') with TagName or ClassName? Since we are not changing the whole body area font sizes. Thanks again! -YN

Answer (score 0):

`getComputedStyle` doesn't work for IE prior to 9.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

A fix might be available here : http://snipplr.com/view/13523/
I didn't test it,

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks Elyx0! I didn't know getComputedStyle is not working for IE prior to 9..... Will take a look at those resources you provided. Thanks! -YN